# Dynamically create CSV file from other CSV files in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix, dataframe

Let's say I have a set of CSV files in a folder called "my data" which is a folder in my working directory.  The CSV files are matrices and looking something like:

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    3    3    3    3
> b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    2    2    2    2
> c
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    3    3    3
[2,]    9    9    9    9
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    9    9    9    9
```

Let's say I have another folder in my working directory called "my results."  In it I want to create another CSV file (call it "my_results") that has the results of the analyses performed on the CSV files in "my data."  For example if I calculated the mean and standard deviation of a, b, and c "my_results" would look like:

```
> my_results
  mean   sd
a  3.0 0.00
b  1.5 0.52
c  6.0 3.10
```

The idea being every row of the new CSV would correspond to one of the CSVs in "my data" and the columns of the new CSV would correspond to a particular analysis run.  Thank you.

Comment: `setwd("mydata"); out <- do.call("rbind", lapply(dir(), function(x) dosomething(data = read.csv(x)))); write.csv(out, file = "../myresults/my_results.csv"); setwd("..")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lapply is your friend:

```
my_data = lapply(list.files("my data", "*.csv"), read.csv)
my_result = lapply(my_data, your_fun())
write.csv(dplyr::bind_rows(my_result), "my data/my results.csv")
```

you get the convienient bind_rows function with package dplyr

Comment: I am sorry but this actually does not appear to be working correctly every time I run the first line all it yields is `list()`  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at the part: list.files("my data", "*.csv"). It should give you a list of all files in directory "my data" ending with ".csv". does directory "my data" exists in your wd? My be you specify the full path in list.files() function.

Comment: It worked when I didn't include the "*.csv" as all of the files in the folder are csv files, but yes "my data" is the wd